# Why GradientPaint draws differently in Java 6 and Java 7/8 on MAC OS

Tags: java

I draw shadow on undecorated `Jframe` with `GradientPaint` class
On Windows OS all is ok. But on Mac OS  when i choose java 7/8 shadow is bigger then in java 6. What i doing wrong?

```java
public class DropShadowPanel extends JPanel() {

//class fields and constructor
.....

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
     super.paintComponent(gr);
     Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gr;

     Rectangle2D r = new Rectangle2D.Double(shadowDistance,shadowDistance, 300, 300);

     draw(g, r, shadowSize);
  }

  private void draw(Graphics2D g, Rectangle2D r, double shadowSize) {
    Color c0 = shadowColor;
    //c1 - full opacity color
    Color c1 = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0);

    double x0 = r.getMinX();
    double y0 = r.getMinY();
    double x1 = r.getMaxX();
    double y1 = r.getMaxY();
    double w = r.getWidth();
    double h = r.getHeight();

    // Left
    g.setPaint(new GradientPaint(
      new Point2D.Double(x0, y0), c0,
      new Point2D.Double(x0 - s, y0), c1));
    g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x0 - s, y0, s, h));

    //draw the remaining sides
    .....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely not you who do anything wrong. It could be general differences from Mac/Win and also differences from Java version.

Up to Java 6, Apple was developing Java but from Java 7, the code was then moved to oracle who is now maintaining it. This transition also included many changes in the source and som GUI behavior and the differences you see in Java 6 vs Java 7/8 is due to that.

I would probably make an if statement and check the os to handle the differences between Win and Java 7/8 on Mac OSX, and forget about how it looks in the old Java 6 on the Mac.